# How to use router.get correctly?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, router, express-handlebars

I am getting data from mongodb and displaying on the routes but one of the routes does not work, below is my code:

routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const data = require('../data');
const gymData = data.gyms;

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      let gymList = await gymData.getTopFive();
      res.render('gymbars/gymlist',{gyms:gymList})

    } catch (e) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });

router.get('/gymcreate',async(req,res) => {
  

  try{
    res.render('gymbars/creategym')
  }
  catch(e){
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

index.js:

```
const gymRoutes = require('./gyms');


const constructorMethod = (app) => {
  app.use('/gyms', gymRoutes);


  app.use('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({ error: 'Not found' });
  });
};

module.exports = constructorMethod;
```

handlebars creategym:

```
 <div>
     <h1> hello </h1>
 </div>
```

The below route just throws internal server error whereas the other route works correctly

```
http://localhost:3000/gyms/gymcreate
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: What is the internal exception that is thrown?  What line of code throws it?

Comment: In ALL your `catch` statements, add `console.log(e)` at the start of your catch block - without that you are flying blind.  That will tell you exactly what exception is being thrown and will likely point you to the source of the problem.

Comment: "One of my routes does not work". Care to tell which one?

Comment: I have mentioned gyms/gymcreate, the code does not even go to that route for some reason

Comment: When I add the route of gymcreate before other routes it loads correctly, what's going on?